# How to select loose text between tags

Tags: css, css-selectors

In cases you find text in HTML code that is not embeded in any tags such as:

```
<sometag> ex1 </sometag>
```

I know many ways to select the text using a p tag or using a class or an id on the div, etc. but my question is: how do you write a css rule for this code as is? Also, I want the rule to be specific for the text so:

sometag {...}

is not desirable because it is more generic.

Thanks for all in advance.

Comment: You mean `sometag {color:red}`?

Comment: if it's a valid html then all the text would certainly be inside `<body>`. And if not, that could be anywhere but such doc is not following any norms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question so that the desired rule would specifically target the text and not be so generic.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Can you show an example of the actual markup you're talking about here..

Comment: I think this is an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/css-3-content-selector

Comment: @zenith, an example would be <div> hello </div> and I wanted to have a rule that would address the text 'hello' without changing the HTML or writing a class for div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, no. There is currently no selector to select TEXT only with CSS. You can (and should) use markup to get the result you're looking for:

HTML:

```
<sometag>
    <span>text here</span>
    <img src='..' />
    some other stuff i don't want to select in my CSS
</sometag>
```

CSS:

```
sometag span{
    /* do something here */
}
```

Comment: +1 for the info., I will mark the reply by @nullability as an answer since it was received earlier than yours.

Comment: i actually answered 6 minutes before but edited many times after (inspect title attribute in chrome) :P either way, no worries

Answer (score 1):

Text nodes cannot have styles applied to them, so anything you need style applied to must be in an element. If you want some of the text inside of your element to be styled differently, wrap it in a span or div, for example.

The wrapping element can then be selected using CSS based on the element type, ID, class, or document order, but *not* by content.

You can, however, use jQuery to select by content using the `:contains` selector: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If "your tag" is a reserved name, like input, div, etc, you can use this:

e.g

```
sometag {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

of course, every tag can receive an id or class, so, you still use for id or class:

id

```
<sometag id="myid"></sometag>

#myid {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

class

```
<sometag class="myclass"></sometag>
.myclass {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: i think OP is concerned about all the text that is not contained within any tags.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted the text without tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html:

```
html {
 color: red;
}
```

or body:

```
body {
 color: red;
}
```

or select everything with *:

```
* {
 color: red;
}
```